# Query com operador AND no Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Tenho uma *query* do elasticsearch ficaria utilizando o operador `AND` para encontrar as duas palavras (carro AND veloz) sendo que deve ter as duas palavras no resultado, não importando se as duas palavras estão no titulo ou se as duas estão na descrição ou se uma palavra está no título e a outra está na descrição, não importa, porém tem que ter as duas palavras no resultado.

A query abaixo está funcionando como `OR` trazendo resultados que tem as duas palavras e resultados que tem apenas uma das palavras.

```
{
"from" : 0, "size" : 10,

    "query": {

       "bool": {
           "must": [
               {
                   "match": {
                       "titulo": {
                       "query": "carro veloz",
                       "fuzziness": 1

                       }
                   }
               },
               {
                   "match": {
                       "descricao": {
                           "query": "carro veloz",
                       "fuzziness": 1
                       }
                   }
               }
       ]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o multi_match com um cross fields, acredito que resolva seu problema

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":{
                "multi_match":{
                    "query":"carro veloz",
                    "operator":"and",
                    "type": "cross_fields",
                    "fields":["descricao", "titulo"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```